# How can I automatically autocomplete libraries, functions, methods in Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am trying to install an extension for Jupyter notebook (version 7.0.4) that allows me to quickly select Python commands, functions, libraries, methods, etc. and not have to write them completely (display a menu of commands in automatic), for this I have followed the instructions in this link but it gives me errors

https://github.com/wenmin-wu/jupyter-tabnine

I don't know if it is due to a new Jupyter Notebook update, since it does not allow using nbextensions, which was an alternative to installing an extension that allows function autocompletion.

Does anyone know what can be done?  If you have an alternative I would appreciate it.

NOTE: Jupyter Notebook has a shortcut for autocomplete, and it is with the TAB key, but it is not efficient, since sometimes it recognizes what you type and most of it does not.

When trying to execute what comes from the instructions in the GitHub link, it gives me this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JymMV.jpg)

Comment: Edit your code and add the complete traceback error as a code block not an image.